# How I retrieve the chanel list using youtube api?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

In an youtube account I have more channels. 
Exists an api call to retrieve all the channels for my account?

I want to upload videos to different channels in function of some video properties. I think that the problem is that I authorize access to my global account don't give automatic authorization for all channels. I have a refresh-token for offline upload (I use this refresh token to retrieve the token for video upload).

If I retrieve channel list from api, always return only one channel and not all my channels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to need to authenticate once for each channel.  The YouTube API is different then other Google APIs.

Refresh tokens are - project, channel based **not** project, user based.

So if you have five channels and you want to access them all you will need five refresh tokens one for each channel.